# MySql AND operator against single column (comparison between two rows of one column)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to execute this query but it's not working.

Would appreciate if anyone helps;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fld_tech_id) 
FROM tbl_tech_properties 
WHERE fld_tech_category_value_id = 236 
    AND fld_tech_category_value_id = 234
```

Comment: can you update your question with table data? please.

Comment: can you pleaes SHARE with us your `tbl_tech_properties` table. So at least we know why the two answers are not correct.

Comment: .. or elaborate on what you mean by "not working". What are the actual results? What results were you expecting instead?

Comment: It's obvious that the query here would produce no results, as it's impossible for something to be equal to 236 AND equal to 234.  At the same time, the question also provides enough information to solve it.

Comment: @TheSmose - True obviously it cannot have two values at once, which is why I upvoted the right answer. That said, my comment was meant as a gentle nudge to a new user that just saying something is "not working" does not really help us to help them ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible for your `WHERE` condition to ever match because it is tested for each row in the table and no single row can have `fld_tech_category_value_id` equal to both 234 and 236 at the same time. Instead you should group by fld_tech_id and check that your group contains two rows.

```
SELECT fld_tech_id
FROM tbl_tech_properties
WHERE fld_tech_category_value_id IN (234, 236)
GROUP BY fld_tech_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fld_tech_category_value_id) = 2
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eabb/1)

Comment: @TheSmose and Mark Byers, can you share what is the real difference between your mighty answer ;) and ours below? Isn't the `distinct` doing the job of `group by` and seriously why do we need to limit result by a count of 2? Please enlighten us.

Comment: People can simply down-vote answers even without a word.. sigh :(

Comment: @bonCodigo - This query requires that the user has BOTH categories 234 and 236.  Your response only required one or the other.  Note in the title, the OP wants an AND.

Comment: PS - The COUNT(DISTINCT) = 2 is a creative, elegant, and efficient way that Mark is identifying that both requirements are met.  It's required for the query to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Why don't you just use</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT fld_tech_id
FROM tbl_tech_properties 
WHERE fld_tech_category_value_id IN (236,234) ;
```

Results based on sample data on the reference:

sample table:

```
FLD_TECH_ID     FLD_TECH_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
1               234
2               256
3               236
3               250
2               226
3               216
1               240
1               236
```

<strike>Results:</strike>

```
FLD_TECH_ID
1
3
```

REFERENCE [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03317/1)

A solution that works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fld_tech_id
FROM tbl_tech_properties AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tbl_tech_properties AS t1
        WHERE t1.fld_tech_id = t.fld_tech_id
          AND t1.fld_tech_category_value_id = 236
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tbl_tech_properties AS t2
        WHERE t2.fld_tech_id = t.fld_tech_id
          AND t2.fld_tech_category_value_id = 234
      )  ;
```

Referernce **[SQL-Fiddle test 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ec1/2)**

Comment: It''s wrong becaus eit returns `1` while there is no row with `(1, 236)`

Comment: `1, 234` exists that's why it returns one.

Comment: Well then, re-read the question and the title: **`AND` operator** against single column (comparison between **two rows** of one column)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Really :) So in simple English can we say that he is looking for a `distinct on multiple columns`?

Comment: No, he is looking for two rows with same value in one column (`fld_tech_id`) and two different values (234 **and** 236) in another column (`fld_tech_category_value_id`).

Comment: Alright, two fields that with same two categories. Like a bird feet ;-)  I felt bird....before now feeling relieved. Thanks for your time and explaining.

Comment: Checking things on 2 (or more) rows means an SQL query more complex than anything with `SELECT whatever FROM one-table WHERE whatever;`

Comment: You are brilliant and head guide. +2 for that. :-D someone else will benefit from your explanation too.

Comment: Two correlated subqueries... ouch.  This will perform significantly slower than the selected answer.